# How to calculate the required value and specify mtrr_gran_size/mtrr_chunk_size?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, ram

I have 16GB RAM and 8GB swap memory. I am running Kubuntu.

upon checking a log after boot i see a section where it says, ***"mtrr_cleanup: can not find optimal value, kernel: [    0.003112] please specify mtrr_gran_size/mtrr_chunk_size "***

```
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003101]  gran_size: 128M     chunk_size: 128M    num_reg: 7      lose cover RAM: 174M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003102]  gran_size: 128M     chunk_size: 256M    num_reg: 9      lose cover RAM: 174M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003103]  gran_size: 128M     chunk_size: 512M    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 174M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003103]  gran_size: 128M     chunk_size: 1G  num_reg: 9      lose cover RAM: 174M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003104]  gran_size: 128M     chunk_size: 2G  num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 174M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003105]  gran_size: 256M     chunk_size: 256M    num_reg: 5      lose cover RAM: 430M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003105]  gran_size: 256M     chunk_size: 512M    num_reg: 5      lose cover RAM: 430M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003106]  gran_size: 256M     chunk_size: 1G  num_reg: 6      lose cover RAM: 430M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003107]  gran_size: 256M     chunk_size: 2G  num_reg: 7      lose cover RAM: 430M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003107]  gran_size: 512M     chunk_size: 512M    num_reg: 5      lose cover RAM: 430M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003108]  gran_size: 512M     chunk_size: 1G  num_reg: 6      lose cover RAM: 430M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003109]  gran_size: 512M     chunk_size: 2G  num_reg: 7      lose cover RAM: 430M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003109]  gran_size: 1G   chunk_size: 1G  num_reg: 4      lose cover RAM: 942M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003110]  gran_size: 1G   chunk_size: 2G  num_reg: 4      lose cover RAM: 942M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003111]  gran_size: 2G   chunk_size: 2G  num_reg: 3      lose cover RAM: 1966M
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003111] mtrr_cleanup: can not find optimal value
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003112] please specify mtrr_gran_size/mtrr_chunk_size
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003115] e820: update [mem 0xcb000000-0xffffffff] usable ==> reserved
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.003118] last_pfn = 0xca000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.010926] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000fd850-0x000fd85f]
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.010959] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.010962] reserving inaccessible SNB gfx pages
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.010967] BRK [0x13a201000, 0x13a201fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.010969] BRK [0x13a202000, 0x13a202fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.010970] BRK [0x13a203000, 0x13a203fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011022] BRK [0x13a204000, 0x13a204fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011023] BRK [0x13a205000, 0x13a205fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011312] BRK [0x13a206000, 0x13a206fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011322] BRK [0x13a207000, 0x13a207fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011332] BRK [0x13a208000, 0x13a208fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011408] BRK [0x13a209000, 0x13a209fff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011499] BRK [0x13a20a000, 0x13a20afff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011746] BRK [0x13a20b000, 0x13a20bfff] PGTABLE
Jul 20 02:45:56 user-System kernel: [    0.011858] BRK [0x13a20c000, 0x13a20cfff] PGTABLE
```

I see a post where it says I have to specify in grub

```
enable_mtrr_cleanup mtrr_spare_reg_nr=1 mtrr_gran_size=32M mtrr_chunk_size=128M
```

*[How and why should I specify mtrr_gran_size/mtrr_chunk_size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244473/how-and-why-should-i-specify-mtrr-gran-size-mtrr-chunk-size)*

Therefore, I am wondering, how to calculate the correct **mtrr_gran_size, mtrr_chunk_size** value and if other parameters would be relevant for my case. I would be very thankful if someone could give me some insights in this.

Comment: The references you yourself provided seem thorough and complete. Nothing to add.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @DougSmythies, thanks for your comment, but i also wanted to know what are those parameter and how are those calculated and what are those used for, etc. Would you happen to know more about those parameters?

Comment: @heynnema, I added those information over here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263425/kubuntu-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-lts-freezing-randomly

Comment: Your `L3 Cache` is disabled. Have you done any tweaks that might have caused that? When you ran `memtest`, did you run all 4/4 test passes?